# need to know if i can write python script in nuke to use pixel analyzer

Tags: python, nuke

i want to use pixel analyzer to get the data of min and max value of image in nuke to use it automatically as to copy this data in a grade note to use it .. i want to know if there is a solution for this

i tried to use min-color script but didn't got what i need .. i searched for a way to use pixel analyzer in nuke script editor but can't find a way
i also tried this code to changes values but want to know i want to add the value of pixel analyzer
for  x in nuke.selectedNodes("Grade"):
print(g)
W=x["whitepoint"].value()
print(W)

```
                if W==1.0:
                   x["whitepoint"].setValue(9)
```

#change name of node

Comment: I think this is what you need (https://learn.foundry.com/nuke/developers/100/pythondevguide/basics.html)

Comment: you're probably looking for the curve tool, not something in coding. curve tool can calculate the min/max pixels, also average luma, but must be run ahead of time